# Single dialogflow agent for several customers

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have done POC on Dialogflow to programmatically create agents and intents. It's working good. However soon I realized I can only create one agent for a project. My use case is to use Dialogflow for multiple customers with their own faq. Hence keeping one agent per customer was making sense but creating a separate project for each customer doesn't seem to be an ideal choice. I am looking for some guidance on using one agent for multiple customers, also making sure there is no conflict. Is this achievable? One way I can think of to use a fulfillment service.  When users asks questions I'll pass customer content along with questions to the fulfillment service. Using customer context I'll try to find to answer specific to that customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the multiple agents in one project setup if you use Dialogflow CX. The limit for this is [100 agents for Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#count_limits).

The downside of this is if you created an agent in Dialogflow ES, you cannot migrate it to Dialogflow CX as it introduces new concepts like flows, pages, and state handlers. See [comparison between ES and CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions).

> CX agent -> This is an advanced agent type that is suitable for large
> or very complex agents. Flows and pages are the building blocks of
> conversation design, and state handlers are used to control
> conversation paths. The CX agent type is summarized in Dialogflow CX
> basics.

Also Dialogflow CX is quite new and its features is not yet as robust as Dialogflow ES. You can read through this [article](https://chatbotsjournal.com/dialogflow-cx-vs-es-a-complete-overview-33580eca529c#:%7E:text=Dialogflow%20ES%20supports%20only%20one,to%20control%20the%20conversation%20paths.) comparing the limitations of CX and ES.

But if you are using features that Dialogflow ES only have, the only option is to have one agent per project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ricco but I am looking got a solution in ES. I understand that I can't have more than one agent but is it possible to use one agent for different customers? For example, one things I tried is sending payload (user context) to fulfillment webhook. It works well as I can use user context ot provide right answer. But this will fail if Dialogflow map user to intent which don't belong that customer.

Comment: The setup that you are aiming is quite difficult to implement. If ever you are able to implement it, you might end up with a very complex agent and it will be difficult to maintain and perform enhancements moving forward.